# Can tensor abelian categories always be embedded into the category of modules?

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories, additive-categories

Let $(\mathcal A, +,\otimes,I)$ a small symmetric monoidal abelian category. I know that $\mathcal A$ can be embedded into the category of $R$-module for a certain ring $R$. But can we make such embedding also preserve the monoidal structure? More precisely:

> Does there exist a commutative ring $R$ such that we can find a strong monoidal fuctor from $\mathcal A$ to $_R\mathsf{Mod}$ which is faithful, full and exact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/47342/36146), and more precisely [this answer by Jacob Lurie](https://mathoverflow.net/a/47344/36146), the answer is in general no.

To sum up the answer, if you have a monoidal functor $F : \mathcal{A} \to \mathsf{Mod}_R$, then $F(I) \cong R$, and thus when $F$ if fully faithful you can recover $R$ as $\operatorname{End}(I)$. This then implies that $F$ is given by $F(A) = \operatorname{Hom}(I,A)$. But there are example of abelian categories for which this isn't a fully faithful embedding, for example the category of complex representations of a finite group.

[Theo Johnson-Freyd however mentions a related result](https://mathoverflow.net/a/47368/36146): the abelian category can be fully faithfully embedded in the category of **bi**modules over $R$, by [a result of Phùng Hô Hài](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0004160).

Comment: Nice example, thanks.