# Symmetric monoidal categories and modules over the unit

Tags: category-theory, modules, yoneda-lemma

Consider a symmetric monoidal category $(C, \otimes, I)$, where $I$ is the unit.
Then there is a restricted Yoneda functor
$$
C \rightarrow Hom(I,I)-mod
$$
taking an object $X$ of $C$ to $Hom(I, X)$, viewed as a right $Hom(I, I)$-module.
I am wondering when this functor is full and faithful. This seems to be the case when $C$ is $R$-mod for a commutative ring $R$ and $\otimes=\otimes_R$, but maybe this case is special since $R$ is also a generator.
There are some counterexamples pointed out here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47342/tensor-variant-of-mitchells-embedding-theorem/47368#47368
for example when $C$ is complex representations of a finite group with tensor product given by tensor product of representations. (also see [Can tensor abelian categories always be embedded into the category of modules?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844777/can-tensor-abelian-categories-always-be-embedded-into-the-category-of-modules))

Are there any mild conditions I can add to make this functor full and faithful? Really, I would like to work with stable infinity categories (or at least with triangulated categories over $\mathbb{Z}$), so maybe the claim has some hope in those settings? (at least, I believe it rules out Lurie's counterexamples).

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. $\textrm{Hom} (I, X) \cong X$ and every object is an $I$-module in a unique way, so the category is equivalent (even isomorphic) to the category of $I$-modules.

Comment: Yes, one can the subcategory of $I$-modules inside $C$ and this subcategory coincides with $C$. Instead, I am viewing $Hom(I,I)$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra (or $R$-algebra for any ground ring $R$) and would like to consider $Hom(I,I)$-modules, which is a faithful (but not full) subcategory of $\mathbb{Z}-mod$. Maybe the title of this post is confusing.

Comment: Then yes, this has to do with $I$ being a generator (but is a stronger condition).